# Difference between "wählen" and "auswählen"?

Tags: difference, word-choice

Both "wählen" and "auswählen" seem to mean "choose or select". Is there a difference in meaning?  When would one be used instead of the other?

Comment: there's is even another one 'erwählen', but it's not used that often and in other situations even though the meaning is a bit similar.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Der Unterschied ist die Auswahl.

Bei "Auswählen" hat man fixe Optionen.

> Beispiel:  Apfel   Banane   Pfirsich

Aus diesen Dingen wird etwas "ausgewählt".

"Wählen" dagegen hat "unlimitierte" Optionen.

> Beispiel: Ich wähle einen Apfel. -> Ich könnte jede erdenkliche Frucht nehmen -- keine fixe Wahlbegrenzung.

Comment: Widerspricht die reale Verwendung nicht dieser Erklärung? Bei einer politischen Wahl hat man gewöhnlich auch nur eine feste Anzahl an Kandidaten oder Parteien, aber man wählt einen/eine davon. Und wenn man an eine Speisekarte denkt, so haben wir es auch mit einer begrenzten Anzahl an Angeboten zu tun (eventuell mit leichtem Verhandlungsspielraum, aber das geht auch nicht unbegrenzt), und der Unterschied zwischen "ein Gericht wählen" und "ein Gericht auswählen" scheint mir eher darin zu liegen, wie "vornehm" man sich ausdrücken möchte.

Comment: kann mich O.R. Mapper nur anschließen. Mir fällt es schwer, ein Beispiel zu finden, wo man nur *auswählen* kann, aber nicht einfach *wählen*. *Auswählen* scheint mir eher ein Spezialfall zu sein, der immer ersetzbar ist (die Implikation einer bestimmten *Menge, aus der ausgewählt wird*, gehört aber dazu).

Answer (score 7):

I admit, it's not easy. I think the difference is

- ***wählen*** means to choose one of them. To stick with the fruits introduced by [this answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/31154/22180): If there are 5 apples and 8 oranges, you could choose an apple. ***No matter which exact one.*** Just an apple. -- Du wählst einen Apfel.
- ***auswählen*** means you want to pick a *particular* apple. Not just *an* apple, but ***exactly this*** apple. -- Du wählst diesen bestimmten Apfel aus.

*Wählen* reminds me of the rumor that some people have N different words for *snow*. In German, there is *wählen* and *auswählen*. That's it.

In English, there is at least

- choose/select - Eine von mehreren Möglichkeiten wählen oder auswählen.
- pick - Einen bestimmten von 5 Äpfeln wählen (oder nehmen) as in "I pick this one" - "Ich nehme den/diesen hier."
- elect/vote - Eine Partei oder eine Person wählen (für sie abstimmen).
- dial - Eine Telefonnummer wählen.

Elect, vote, and dial have special meanings. Although they all translate to *wählen*, the distinction between *anyone* and *particular* doesn't apply to them.

Comment: "In German, there is *wählen* and *auswählen*. That's it." And *erwählen*. And *aussuchen*. And *selektieren* (in computer contexts, where *auswählen* is ambiguous).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Hmm. Da hast Du mich zu Recht erwischt! ;-) _Aussuchen_ gefällt mir gut; ich würde das als Synonym zu _auswählen_ sehen. _Erwählen_ klingt nach Gottheit o.ä. (Die Auserwählte). _Selektieren_ hat mitunter eine sehr üble Nebenbedeutung, wenn es nicht im Computer-Umfeld benutzt wird. Aber stimmt schon, ein bisschen mehr als "wählen" gibt es im Deutschen schon, wenngleich die Alternativen eher exotisch sind.

Comment: Was für eine üble Nebenbedeutung hat *selektieren* denn? Neben dem Computer-Kontext fällt mir zu dem Wort im Moment eigentlich nichts außer dem biologischen Zusammenhang der evolutionären Selektion ein.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Bei "Selektion" denke ich sofort auch an "Rampe" ([Wiki](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selektion_(Konzentrationslager))), aber das ist wahrscheinlich nicht allgemeingültig bzw. individuell verschieden.

Comment: Ok, verstehe - weder der Begriff *Selektion* noch der Begriff *Rampe* ist mir bisher mit Nazi-Bezug untergekommen, aber das ist dann natürlich auch zu beachten.

Comment: Beim politischen Wählen fällt vielleicht noch ins Gewicht, dass ich zwar Partei A wähle, aber damit nur an einem Prozess teilnehme. Wenn die Mehrheit anders wählt habe ich durch meine Wahl nichts ausgewählt.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper _Rampe_ alleine hat für mich auch keinen Nazi-Bezug; ich glaube für niemanden, der nicht persönlich betroffen war. (Achtung, sehr dünnes Eis). Es ist einfach eine schräge Auffahrt oder so ähnlich. Mehr nicht. Aber mit _Selektion_ verbindet man schon -- zumindest auf den zweiten Blick -- _auch_ die Selektion in Auschwitz. Wie gesagt, das ist bestimmt individuell sehr verschieden. Wäre ich Biologe, würde ich sicher an die ursprüngliche Bedeutung denken. Als IT'ler "selecte _(sic!)_ ich bestimmte Zeilen einer Tabelle" (man möge mir hier verzeihen), anstatt sie zu "selektieren".

Comment: Je nach Kontext gibt es noch viel, viel, viel mehr Synonyme. Ausersehen, auslesen, optieren, (aus)sieben, voten, abstimmen, usw. usf. Zu behaupten, dass es im Deutschen nur zwei Wörter gibt, für wohlbemerkt vier verschiedene (in der Antwort genannte) Kontexte, ist schon sehr gewagt.

Comment: Is there some kind of book that explains these aspects?  How the derivation using prefixes changes the meaning...  I saw no book that explains how the German think about these prefixes...